# Can someone explain this JPQL query for me?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

What is this JPQL query?

```
SELECT e
FROM Department d JOIN d.employees e JOIN e.projects p
WHERE 
e.salary = :amount and 
d.name = :name and 
p.location = :location"
```

I understand the the first JOIN in which the `Department` gets joined by `Employee` entity but what's the reason for the second join while we are just selecting `e`?

Comment: Post that `WHERE` clause, then. In particular, does it use `p` as a filter?

Comment: @chrylis, yes it does. Updated.

Comment: so the question is answered.

Comment: Is this going from 1st table to the 2nd table and eventually the 3rd one and pulls of some entity from 2nd table?

Comment: This is a very strange query, and the `:employeeId` seems out of place, unless the idea is to ask in one single query whether a specific employee is a member of a specific department and assigned to a specific project.

Comment: @chrylis, I don't exactly remember the where clause. Think of it as some other fields. Like `e.something = :somethingSpecial`.

Comment: Then we need the *actual* where clause. Basically, the reason for joining `p` is to be able to select the employees who are associated with some project(s).

Comment: I would try to answer this question but he keeps changing the JPQL

Comment: @AdamGent, haha :) It's done. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining to the projects of departments is necessary, because single project is later on needed in WHERE clause:

```
p.location = :location
```

Projects is a collection. Consequently `e.projects` is collection valued path expression. It is not possible navigate through collection valued path expression. Following construct is not expected to work, because collection does not have `location` property.

```
e.projects.location = :location
```